# How to solve error “Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined” in Bootstrap next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating a React app using Next.js and Bootstrap 
but when am trying to import Bootstrap.js i got the error

[image]

I tried to import Jquery before Bootstrap.js but that isn't working and here is my Header component code

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import '../static/style.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'

const Header = (props) => (
    <div>
        <Head>
            <meta charSet="UTF-8"/>
            <title></title>
            <meta name="" content=""/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
            <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
            <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
        </Head>
        <div className="container">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                            <MenuItem category="products" img="menu1.jpg" text="Products & Solutions" content={
                                <>
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                    <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </>
                            }>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </li>
```

Comment: @AshishKamble can you tell what do you mean by entry of  "bootstrap.min.css"???

Comment: @DaShInGSid i think bootstrap file is not available, or not downloaded somehow i may be wrong